# Linux user account 'nagent' deleted and re-added in secure log

Tags: security, centos, logging

The following lines appear in my CentOS `secure` log file:

```
Oct 27 21:10:59 servr userdel[7270]: delete user 'nagent'
Oct 27 21:10:59 servr userdel[7270]: removed group 'nagent' owned by 'nagent'
Oct 27 21:11:04 servr useradd[7333]: new group: name=nagent, GID=502
Oct 27 21:11:04 servr useradd[7333]: new user: name=nagent, UID=502, GID=502, home=/home/nagent, shell=/bin/bash
```

I did not do this, and I am the only one to my knowledge that has access to this server.

**What do these log entries mean?  Is there a process that might do this, or has someone else broken into my system?**

> Edit 1 - Running suggestions:

```
find / -user nagent -iname "*" -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-rw----. 1 nagent mail 0 Oct 27 21:11 /var/spool/mail/nagent
find: `/proc/14041/task/14041/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/14041/task/14041/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/14041/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/14041/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
total 28
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Oct 27 21:11 CMData
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Oct 27 21:11 CMSetting
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  615 Oct 27 21:11 nagent.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  615 Oct 27 21:11 nagent.conf.Save
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5510 Oct 27 21:11 nagent_download.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1665 Oct 27 21:11 uninstall.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 nagent nagent 18 Sep 22 12:40 /home/nagent/.bash_logout
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 nagent nagent 124 Sep 22 12:40 /home/nagent/.bashrc
-rw-r--r--. 1 nagent nagent 176 Sep 22 12:40 /home/nagent/.bash_profile
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nagent nagent 4096 Aug 18  2010 extensions
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nagent nagent 4096 Aug 18  2010 plugins
total 0
total 0
```

I am not sure how to interpret this output...?  Is this part of SendMail, I believe it might be?  Googling `SendMail "nagent"` returns results discussing `SendMail Network Agent`.  Not certain on this though.  I am running `SendMail SMTP server`.

> Edit 2 - contents of /etc/nagent.conf

```
[main]
    logfilename=/var/log/n-central/nagent.log
    loglevel=2
    homedir=/home/nagent/
    thread_limitation=50
    poll_delay=1
    datablock_size=20

[soap]
    Server=127.0.0.1
    Port=80
    Protocol=http
    ApplianceID=1
    Server_ro=no
```

FYI - port 80 is blocked on this server with the iptables entry:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

The contents of `/home/ncm/nable/nagent-rhel5.1_64/nagent_download.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on failure --------------------------------------------------------------
function exitOnFailure {
        echo "" >> $LOGGER
        echo "Download failed" >> $LOGGER
        echo "==================================== END DOWNLOAD ================================" >> $LOGGER
        exit 1
}

# Show usage -------------------------------------------------------------------
function usage {
        echo "" >> $LOGGER
        echo "Usage: nagent_download.sh URL InstallerName FileSize MD5Sum Destination [Proxy] [ProxyUsername] [ProxyPassword]" >> $LOGGER
        echo "Example: nagent_download.sh http://192.168.20.128/download/100.0.0.0/rhel5.1_64/N-central/nagent-rhel5.1_64.tar.gz nagent-rhel5.1.tar.gz 2785964 aea43c12d2a86d76ea95bbbf0bf625e9 /tmp" >> $LOGGER

        exitOnFailure
}

# Verify given arguments -------------------------------------------------------
function verifyArguments {
        if [ -z "$URL" ]
        then
                echo "No download url provided" >> $LOGGER
                usage
        fi

        if [ -z "$INSTALLER" ]
        then
                echo "No installer name provided" >> $LOGGER
                usage
        fi

        if [ -z "$INSTALLER_FILESIZE" ]
"/home/ncm/nable/nagent-rhel5.1_64/nagent_download.sh" 167L, 5335C
```

> Edit 3

```
netstat -antp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57808               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2190/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      2027/java           
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      2027/java           
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2027/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:58580      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:3306       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:58380      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:3306       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.18:443     ::ffff:70.192.192.180:10757 ESTABLISHED 2027/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:58280      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:3306       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:58480      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:3306       TIME_WAIT   -
```

> Edit 4

The nagent folder in `home` was created with the `secure` log events.  I don't know if that is significant:

```
drwx------.  6 nagent   nagent    4096 Oct 27 21:11 nagent
```

Also displaying running processes `ps aux | less` has these related results

```
...
root      7393  0.0  0.0 108432  1176 ?        S    Oct27   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/nagent start
root      7396  0.0  0.0 108164  1404 ?        S    Oct27   0:00 /bin/bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; nagent -f /home/nagent/nagent.conf
root      7397  0.0  0.0 219960  7100 ?        Sl   Oct27   0:15 nagent -f /home/nagent/nagent.conf
...
```

Comment: @Begueradj - That is not my account.  I think that it's a processes account, but I do not know.  I am not by any measure a Linux admin.

Comment: Some daemons will create accounts but generally only at installation time.

Comment: Ok, did you install/reinstall something on `Oct 27` around 21:10?

Comment: @Begueradj  I changed some iptable rules and restarted, but I have not installed or uninstalled anything for some time now.

Comment: @Begueradj - This is a production server.  If that account is legitimate and a daemon is using it, it could break or cause undesirable side effects.  I need to understand this first before acting.

Comment: the IP number 192.168.20.128 is not a part of the general WAN, it is a [private IP number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can begin by search if the user nagent is owner of files on your system:

```
find / -user nagent -iname "*" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

And you can look at if some process have been launched and not again stopped by this user:

```
ps -ef | grep nagent
```

In yours logs, you can look at the activity of your server around the 27 october 21:10, something like this:

```
cat /var/log/<your file> | grep "Oct 27 21:1"
```

---

EDIT 1:
Some files has been modified/created during the same time of the userdel and useradd:

> ```
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  615 Oct 27 21:11 nagent.conf
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  615 Oct 27 21:11 nagent.conf.Save
> -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5510 Oct 27 21:11 nagent_download.sh
> -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1665 Oct 27 21:11 uninstall.sh
> ```

Can you read `nagent.conf` and `nagent_download.sh` ?

---

EDIT 2:
Can you verify if you have a process which listen on the TCP port 80:

```
 netstat -antp | grep 80
```

Have you done a update/upgrade maybe the 27 oct 21h ?

---

EDIT 3:

From the `netstat command`, you have the port 80 opened by a process with PID of 2027:java. Moreover, this process opens the 8089 and the 443 which has a connection with a machine :

```
  ::ffff:192.168.1.18:443     ::ffff:70.192.192.180:10757 ESTABLISHED     2027/java
```

To have more infos, you can do `ps -ef | grep 2027` and see details on the commands and the parent process of it.

From your ps command, you have a service named nagent in /etc/init.d/nagent

In conclusion, you or someone have installed the agent of the N-central software (the files and process match with the doc done by @ojs in his solution). Now, you must search who and how this software has been installed.

To know which package has been installed: 
`ls -ltr /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list`

You can look the .bash_history in the home directory of the users of your server

Comment: Curious - `find / -user naget -iname "*" -exec ls -l {} \;`
find: `naget' is not the name of a known user

Comment: sorry, a error of my part, I edited my answer, you can read `nagent` and not `naget` :)

Comment: I added Edit 1 in the answer

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: I added Edit 2 in the answer

Comment: I have not updated/upgraded anything - I added `fail2ban` a few days ago.  I have updated my post to your edit.

Comment: The only thing I find on google is a Network agent from Solarwinds N-central.

Comment: I added Edit 3 in the answer

Comment: At his point I am assuming this `is not a wanted or needed account`, and I have removed it.  I also killed related processes.  I am not yet sure how this account or related activity could happen.  I appreciate your guidance and will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to point to product by [Solarwinds N-able](http://www.n-able.com/). At least they used to use `/home/nagent` and their packages were named `nagent-rhel`. I found reference to this in an [old document](http://www.techpart.net/documentation/N-central_CustomerManual.pdf) from them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install [Neptune](https://www.neptune.io/index.html)?

`nagent` might be the user for the Neptune agent, added automatically when you install the package. By default the user is `neptuneioagent`, but your distro might have changed the user name.

Comment: No - I don't know what that is.